# What cause WebException when consuming Web Service on Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, windows-mobile-6.5, .net-cf-3.5

My application consume a web service but always receive the following expception on first try after the application is started: **System.Net.WebException** with inner exception **System.InvalidOperationException** and **Could not evaluate expression** message. This only occurs for web service and not on HttpWebRequest. Any clue?

```
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters, WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       ...
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
       at Example.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the problem is because my Squid Proxy 2.7 is returning HTTP Status 417 when my web service sends Expect 100 header. To solve this I have to add the following line before invoking the web service.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```